# stack in reverse order

Tags: python-3.x, stack

trying to create a function which prints a stack in reverse.

this is the code i have so far:

```
def read_ints(num):            
  integer = int(input("Enter a integer:"))
  stack = Stack() 
  for i in range(integer): 
    if stack.is_empty() == True:
      stack.push(num) 
    else: 
      stack.pop()
```

I have created a test case:

```
read_integers(3)
4
3
2
```

so when i type 4, 3 and 2. the output should be 2,3 4. 
any help would be great thanks ! at the moment its just printing out one integer three times. So I'm getting 3, 3,3

Comment: Is `num` supposed to be how many integers you want to read?

Comment: yeah thats what num is :)

Comment: The function names here don't match, the definition of `Stack` is not provided, and at no point does the code you provide produce any non-prompt output. So we have no idea what you're printing, if you're printing, or what any of your code logic is. It's extremely important to know what order stuff was pushed to understand what you even mean by "printing in reverse order"; do you mean print in the order stuff was pushed (FIFO, the reverse of the natural order of a stack, which is LIFO), or print from end of underlying list to beginning (LIFO, reverse for a `list`, but natural order of stack)?

Comment: You asked about the same program but a different error just the other day, right? Getting a deja vu here and I don't know if it's just me. Anyway, if `stack` is a `list`, just `stack.pop(0)`. Otherwise, reverse the list (copy or in place) and pop the last element

Comment: @ShadowRanger [Here's the `Stack class`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392627/pop-elements-from-stack). OP can tell us if it's the current version, I guess.

Comment: Also, side-note: `if stack.is_empty() == True:` (like all explicit comparisons to `True` and `False`) is likely wrong or at least less than ideal. If `is_empty` is a logically boolean test, it doesn't matter if it returns `True` or `False` specifically; just test `if stack.is_empty():` and it will be both faster, simpler, and more Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

```
  integer = int(input("Enter a integer:"))
```

This line needs to be *inside* your for loop - otherwise you're accepting input once and then looping three times, which is silly.

```
for i in range(integer):
```

Assuming you want to read `num` integers, you should loop up to `range(num)`, not `range(integer)`.

```
if stack.is_empty() == True:
  stack.push(num) 
else: 
  stack.pop()
```

This is probably not what you want -- you're only adding to the stack if it's empty, or else immediately popping. Instead, you want to push all the numbers on first, then pop them all at the end. Also, you've confused `num` and `integer` again - you want to add your *input* to the stack, not your loop limit!

So, assuming your `Stack.pop` prints out what's being popped:

```
for i in range(num):
    integer = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    stack.push(integer)

while not stack.is_empty():
    stack.pop()
```